# Neo4j slow concurrent merges

Tags: neo4j

I have been experiencing some extremely bad slowdowns in Neo4j, and having spent a few days on the issue now, I still can't figure out why. I'm really hoping someone here can help. I've also tried the neo slack support group already, but to no avail.

My setup is as follows: the back-end is a django app that connects through the *official drivers* (pip package neo4j-driver==1.5.0) to a dockerized *Neo4j Enterprise* 3.2.3 instance. The data we write is added in infrequent bursts of around 15 concurrent merges to the same portion of the graph, and is triggered when a user interacts with some part of our product (each interaction causing a separate merge).

Each merge operation is the following query:

```
MERGE (m :main:entity:person {user: $user, task: $task, type: $type, 
text: $text}) 
ON CREATE SET m.source = $list, m.created = $timestamp, m.task_id=id(m) 
ON MATCH SET m.source = CASE 
    WHEN $source IN m.source THEN m.source 
    ELSE m.source + $list 
    END SET m.modified = $timestamp 
RETURN m.task_id AS task_id;
```

A **PROFILE** of this query looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU8b6.png). As you can see, the individual processing time is in the ms range. We have tested running this 100+ times in quick succession with no issues. We have a Node key configured as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QioFq.png) schema.

The running system however seems to seize up and we see execution times for these queries hit as high as 2 minutes! A snapshot of the running queries looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJKLp.png).

Does anyone have any clues as to what may be going on?

Further system info:

```
ls data/databases/graph.db/*store.db* | du -ch | tail -1
    249.6M  total

find data/databases/graph.db/schema/index -regex '.*/native.*' | du -hc | tail -1
    249.6M  total

ps
    1 root     297:51 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/conf:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* -server -Xms8G -Xmx8G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPr

printenv | grep NEO
    NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=4G
    NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=8G
```

The machine is has 16GB total memory and there is nothing else running on it.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j, and which version of the driver?

Comment: neo4j-driver==1.5.0

Neo Enterprise 3.2.3

Comment: What happens if you prefix those queries with `CYPHER 3.1 planner=RULE ` ? Does the burst of concurrent merges work as expected in that case?

Comment: No luck. Investigating the debug logs it seems that the queries spend most of their time waiting which suggests a locking issue?

Comment: [Enable query logging](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/query-logging/) if you can, with timing and page logging enabled, and see where the time spent is going. CPU is for executing, high waiting typically indicates lock contention.